# Why was I denied boarding on a flight with a transfer through Hong Kong?

Tags: visas, transit, hong-kong, syrian-citizens, hkg

I booked a flight on Cathay but I was denied boarding from China to Europe via Hong Kong. The operator claimed that I need visa to transit (Syrian national) although I had one single booking and my transfer was only 3 hours and I met the requirements of my final destination.

They forced me to refund the ticket so I lost the refund fees, what can I do in this situation? I am worried that the operator input HK as the final destination just to get rid of me.

Although the IATA system gives the same message to mainland Chinese passengers they still let them transfer through HK to Europe, so why did they deny it to me?

Comment: "I am worried that the operator input HK as the final destination just to get rid of me." This seems incredibly unlikely. What would be in it for them that's worth the hassle and bad press?

Answer (score 63):

According to both [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/) (the system used by most airlines to confirm visa requirements) and the [IATA Travel Center](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) a Syrian national DOES require a visa to transit Hong Kong, even if only for a few hours, and even when travelling on a single ticket.

As you did not have a valid visa to transit Hong Kong, you were correctly denied boarding in China.

Comment: Note that this is by far not an isolated case. Many European countries similarly have requirements for airport transit visas for nationals of some countries even if they are on a single booking and remain airside.

Comment: Primary source for those interested: part II of https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html

Comment: But WISEHEAD should not have been sold this booking without confirming that he has the Visa. It does seem as he or she has been scammed for the refund fee.

Comment: @Kaz huh what? It’s never been the airline’s responsibility to verify people have the correct visas at the time of buying the ticket.

Comment: @Kaz that makes absolutely no sense - airlines check your visa at the time of boarding, since you can very well obtain your visa after purchasing the booking. Hell, having the booking even helps your case for obtaining an US short-stay visa

Comment: @Kaz: it is too complex: there are too many special cases (and it is not just about visa, you may also be on a black list of company or of police). But note: often you find a link during booking, about requirements (often to an external site), and on final confirmation step you may get asked (together other things) about having requirements to travel (including visa).

Comment: @Kaz One of the requirements for getting a transit visa is "where the application is for a transit visa/entry permit, he/she holds an onward ticket to the place of his/her destination unless the destination is the Mainland of China or Macao." So in many cases you can't _get_ the transit visa until after you have your tickets. https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit_transit.html

Comment: I don't think airline should *check* the visa when they sell the ticket, but it would be a good practice to *make sure client knows* what visas will he need to board.

Comment: @jcaron I recall once being turned back on a trip through Russia->Latvia->Lithuania due to not having a transit visa for Latvia. Did not matter that nobody was leaving the train and it was at night. Was like 20 years ago, too.

Comment: @Mołot I suspect airlines don't want to get in the business of telling someone they're OK if they do X, and then someone gets there with X and it turns out their algorithm was wrong or things changed.

Comment: @AzorAhai something like "Please check the visa rules for Hong Kong transit" would be helpful and safe.

Comment: The Cathay Pacific website includes a page which cover this under the 'Travel preparation' section on their website, including a link to the IATA website I included in my answer.  https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_CA/prepare-trip/visa-information/overview.html

Comment: @Mołot But all airlines I use already do that. Whenever I book there is a disclaimer that I should check if I fulfill the necessary visa requirements, often with one or multiple links. Doing anything more specific than that would bring you into exactly the dilemma that if you get it wrong you may turn out to be liable in one way or another.